# Width of div is wrong (flex)

Tags: css, flexbox

I need a div with 70px. But if you inspect this element, it has 64px. In my app, the green div is a sidebar with js animation. I need to "push" the content (it has 100% of width).

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">  
  <div style="width:70px; background: green; height: 50px"></div>
  <div style="width: 100%; background: rgba(0,0,0,.4)">a</div>
</div>
```

how can i have 70px on green div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `flex-shrink: 0;` to the element that shouldn't become smaller:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">  
  <div style="width:70px; background: green; height: 50px; flex-shrink: 0;"></div>
  <div style="width: 100%; background: rgba(0,0,0,.4)">a</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the 100% width on the second div and replace with `flex:1`

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">  
  <div style="width:70px; background: green; height: 50px"></div>
  <div style="flex:1; background: rgba(0,0,0,.4)">a</div>
</div>
```